# Windows 10 Automatically disabling Hyper V after each restart

Tags: windows-10, powershell, hyper-v, windows-services, hyper-v-manager

I want to work with Docker and Hyper V all the time. My Windows 10 is disabling the Hyper V automatically after each restart.

I had to run the following powershell command every time and restart again to make it work.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

Is there any other way we can make the Hyper V getting enabled automatically every time?

Comment: Is Hyper-V enabled in:  Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features ?